# how to get UTC time in micro-seconds with leap seconds

Tags: c++, boost

How to get UTC time in micro-seconds with leap seconds adjusted?
I am using `boost::universal_clock()`

```
 boost::posix_time::time_duration utc_time =
      boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::universal_time() -
      boost::posix_time::from_time_t(0);
  int64_t total_microsec = utc_time.total_microseconds();
```

But the result of this is same as

```
std::chrono::time_point_cast<std::chrono::duration<int64_t, std::microseconds>>(
             std::chrono::system_clock::now())
      .time_since_epoch()
      .count();
```

which seems that boost is not adjusting leap seconds. However when I use C `gmtime()` I get different result:

```
  time_t mytime;

  struct tm *ptm;

  time(&mytime);  // Get local time in time_t

  ptm = gmtime(&mytime);  // Find out UTC time

  time_t utctime = mktime(ptm);  // Get UTC time as time_t
```

How to achieve it using boost library?

Comment: Does the OS provide the current time at the microsecond resolution?

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis using seconds_clock is not going to make a difference here. I am comparing seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Howard Hinnant's date/time library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html) this is very easy:

```
#include "date/tz.h"
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    auto now = floor<microseconds>(utc_clock::now());
    cout << now << '\n';
    cout << now.time_since_epoch() << '\n';
    cout << clock_cast<system_clock>(now).time_since_epoch() << '\n';
}
```

This is a preview of the [C++20 additions to `<chrono>`](http://eel.is/c++draft/time.clock.utc), but in `namespace date`.

`utc_clock` counts time since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC *including* leap seconds.  The `clock_cast` casts the `time_point` from this clock back to that of `system_clock` just for comparison purposes.

This program just output for me:

```
2019-08-10 00:19:04.388788
1565396371388788µs
1565396344388788µs
```

[Some installation required.](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html#Installation)

Comment: Thanks so much. Your library looks great. However, I cannot use any external library in my project.

Comment: Like boost? ;-)  Well, wait a year and then upgrade to C++20.